# Which Java collection's Linked list adds in O(1) when given an element?

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap, complexity-theory

i need to insert into a very large LinkedList, whose elements i hold in a fast-access HashMap.
it's important to keep the list in order (which is not the natural order of the keys).

i thought it would be possible to hash the linked list nodes, then insert directly on the node (getting the node from the map + insert in a linked list == constant time).

however, i couldn't find any Java collection that would do that or similar...
i'm currently using LinkedHashMap, which doesn't meet the requirements above.

thanks, asaf :-)

Comment: thank you all for replaying.

 of course i don't mean to generically sort n elements in o(n)...

i get the list ordered from, lets say, a server. then i display a subset of the list, using the hash to get the info i need for each entry, and sometimes i reset the display by going through the list and getting the original order. then i get updates like 'add entry x after y'.

i want to preserve order (which now isn't the insertion order), but i don't want to pay for scanning the whole list.

if i was to right my own DS, i'd get x, then (using the doubly linked list) add y after it.

Comment: hmmm, how do i newline in comments? sorry for that.

Comment: Maybe you should add an example to your question with your data structure, what you get when wherefrom and how it has to be changed, if you want further input. It's hard to follow (at least for me)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the LinkedList should be sorted after each insertion, I doubt you will be able to find such a data structure, as it implies that you would get a sorting algorithm with time complexity O(n), which has been proven impossible. (The lowest bound on sorting is O(n log n).) The best you could get on insertion is O(log n).

Then you can use the [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use a TreeSet or TreeMap. Inserts are O(log(n)) but remember that means LOG.  So if you have 4 billion entries the runtime is O(32).  If you have 2<sup>64</sup> entries, then an insert takes O(64), so it's not really a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

As it's "important to keep the list in order" your effectively doing an [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) which has a best-case-performance of O(n). Additionally, you must not confuse hashing with sorting - as the order of a hash isn't defined as it depends on the size of the underlying hashtable. (Using a hash to insert would only be useful if you know the predecessor or successor of the node you want to insert)

Comment: 'your effectively doing an insertion sort which has a best-case-performance of O(n)' - if the list is kept ordered binary search may be used for finding insertion index and insertion complexity is O(log n) then.

Comment: A binary search with a complexity of O(log n) is only possible if the complexity for random access to an indexed element is O(1), which is not the case for a linked list.

Comment: The author provided us with information that he uses dedicated HashMap for indexed access to the list elements which allows to have O(1) complexity for random element access.

Comment: If the author is talking about a `java.util.LinkedList` (which I suppose he is), there is no way to access elements randomly in O(1)

Comment: Did you check the initial message? 

'i need to insert into a very large LinkedList, whose elements i hold in a fast-access HashMap.'

Comment: I did read the message. But the term 'elements' is ambiguous. I assumed elements being values of the list - mainly as it isn't possible to access the nodes (`LinkedList.Entry<E>` - where the value is stored as the field `E element` btw) of a LinkedList. I didn't expect it a custom implementation of a linked list - if it is, it shouldn't be called LinkedList to avoid confusion. But back to the main problem: If it's possible to access (randomly) *and* insert nodes in O(1), it would be possible to do an insertion sort in O(log n) as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you must keep your list in order - but that it is not the natural order of the keys, I hear you saying that you must preserve insertion order.

But then I don't know why LinkedHashMap doesn't meet your requirements.

Can you explain what LinkedHashMap fails to do?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you don't have good access to the list. So you can't use the hashmap to jump to the list node and then insert an element after that node.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is it insertion order you need to preserve?  2) Why do you say that about LinkedHashMap?  I'll test and post a certain response later, but from the docs, LinkedHashMap _is_ a hash map, but one which uses original insertion order as the order for iteration.